# How can i add new script and load it on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to add new script and want to it only on scroll. i tried this but didn't worked. any idea why?

```
      $(window).scroll(function() {
       var heightT = $('body').offset().top,
           outerH = $('body').outerHeight(),
           windowH = $(window).height(),
           wS = $(this).scrollTop();

       if (wS > (heightT+outerH-windowH-200)){
          <script src="myscript.js"></script>
       }
```

Comment: As you have many questions but none marked as an answer, please reivew [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script dynamically.

```
let scriptAdded = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
       var heightT = $('body').offset().top,
           outerH = $('body').outerHeight(),
           windowH = $(window).height(),
           wS = $(this).scrollTop();

       if (wS > (heightT+outerH-windowH-200) && !scriptAdded){
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.setAttribute('src','myscript.js');
          document.head.appendChild(script);
          // So that not add many time
          scriptAdded = true;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then you can use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

```js
$.getScript("your/script.js", function(){
    console.log("Script was loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we want to make sure that a script is loaded correctly.
You can try and make use of listeners when try and load a script dynamically, and to be sure that the script is loaded correctly.

You can listen to Mutation Events but it is not longer recommended because of performance  and browser compatibility issues

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

A second alternative is attach events to the appended childNode.
In fact, the appendChild method returns the childNode and it can listen to 3 events that are fired by window.

Here a potential vanilla javascript implementation:

```
    const id = "scriptID";
    const src = "your script src";  
    const scriptElement = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!scriptElement) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");

      if (script) {
        script.src = src;       
        script.id = id;

        const loadError = () => throw new Error("can't load the script")
        const loadSuccess = () => console.log("loaded");
        const attachedScript = document.body.appendChild(script);
        const onloadEvent = attachedScript.addEventListener("load", loadSuccess);
        const onerrorEvent = attachedScript.addEventListener("error", loadError);
        const onavortEvent = attachedScript.addEventListener("abort", loadError);

      } else {
        const error = "can't load the script";
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    }
```

However, the above solution listens to the load event that is fired by window when page is fully loaded (including assets), that is in contrast with DocumentContentLoaded event that is fired when DOM is loaded but it does not wait for assets to be loaded:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

What is wrong with the above is that the load event should be used on first load and not when DOM is mutated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

A more elegant solution would be make use instead of MutationObserver, that is meant to replace the MutationEvents feature:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
    const id = "scriptID";
    const src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.js";   
    const scriptElement = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!scriptElement) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");

      if (script) {
        script.src = src;       
        script.id = id;

        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => { 
          console.log("change being done");
          observer.disconnect();
        });
        const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };
        observer.observe( document.body, config);
        document.body.appendChild(script)

      } else {
        const error = "can't load the script";
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    }
```

MutationObserver looks for DOM mutation but it does not trigger when a script is actually loaded, so using the load event from window as well would make the solution stronger.

Now, why all of this is needed for just append a script in the DOM?
Some of the reasons are:

- one thing is appending a script in the DOM, but what counts is when a script is loaded
- we should be very careful when listening to DOM manipulation events, because it can easily bring to a performance degradation
- there is no need to listen to error when appending a child as the cases of fail are rare